# TsFresh pandas concat either takes a long time with no progress

Tags: python, pandas

I am using TsFresh version 0.7.1 and have had a script using TsFresh to generate features since at least version 0.5.0 if not earlier.

I was running my script that contains these generic steps:

1. format data into a pandas DataFrame and a pandas series for the classes
2. `extracted_features = extract_features(dataframe, column_id="id", column_sort="time", parallelization="per_sample")`
3. `impute(extracted_features)`
4. `return list(select_features(extracted_features, classes))`
5. save the list of features to a json file to be calculated in our Dataflow pipeline

Currently my script is getting stuck on step 2, specifically in TsFresh's function **feature_extraction.extraction._extract_features_parallel_per_sample**, on this line: `df_tmp = pd.concat(dfs_kind, axis=0).astype(np.float64)`

GitHub code here: [TsFresh](https://github.com/blue-yonder/tsfresh/blob/master/tsfresh/feature_extraction/extraction.py#L255)

Does anyone know how I can speed this up? pd.concat seems to be really slow.

Thank you

Comment: Depends a lot on the dataframes in `dfs_kind`

Comment: Do you mean the dataframes size because that makes sense that it would be slower for bigger dataframes but is there a way to speed that up?

Comment: Yes, that matters... but I also mean, what do the column indices look like?  Are the `pd.MultiIndex`?  Do they all have the same columns?  Are they already sorted?  Can I expect that all dataframes will have the same exact columns in the same exact order?  What are the `dtypes`?  Are they object?  Are they mixed type, `int` and `string`?  Are there nulls?

Comment: Currently I removed all but one data column so each dataframe has an id column, time column and a single data field column in the form of a numpy float64. The dataframe is built based on different recorded sessions so it is roughly sorted by the time column.

Comment: id is a string, time is datetime in string format, and the data field is a float

Comment: Hi, I am the author of tsfresh. It is really hard to judge what is going wrong here. Can you create a minimal example in an ipython notebook with sample data? What you describe could be caused by different things, e.g. wrong naming of columns, non fitting parallelization parameters and so on

Comment: Hi @MaxBenChrist I debugged the code better and left a message on Gitter (which you responded to) and realized the root issue causing my code to error out was multiprocessing's queue running out of memory so I had to adjust the chunk size. I still have not figured out the optimal chunk size to not error out but I will take some time to make an ipython notebook to help with this question.

Comment: Alright. It is not trivial to find the best chunksize, there are tradeoffs between interpreter overhead and cpu utilization that makes it hard to find the best parameters.

Comment: Okay I think this question/issue was completely my fault and is definitely not a TsFresh issue. Our larger data files seem to be too big  (~50MB) for even 1 chunksize. Our smaller data files (~2MB) work just fine so I am going to have to process our larger files into smaller pseudo files to be able to pass all of our data through TsFresh. Sorry for my lack of thinking!